# php str_replace failed to replace single character

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I'm trying to replace single character of a string that is normal numbers to arabic.

I have

```
  $er_num = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
  $ar_num = array('٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩');
  echo str_replace($er_num,$ar_num,'12');
```

It works fine for multi digits.. but when it comes for single digit, it didn't..

```
  echo str_replace($er_num,$ar_num,'1');
```

Comment: It work well for me (php7). Maybe you php is not set to UTF8? Check the php.ini file for: `default_charset = "UTF-8"`

Comment: sorry not working.. @ michaelbn
@ sinitram

Comment: It works - http://ideone.com/N6o9VU

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew .. I'm using this in TCPDF .. even I've added the UTF-8 ..  its not working.

Comment: Did you do it as in the tutorial? I see something like `$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);`

Comment: yes. as it is

TCPDF('P', 'px', 'a4', true, 'UTF-8', false);